# Maven archetype for JSP

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a problem. I want to create Java Project which uses Servlets and JSP. So I create new Maven project and choose maven-archetype-webapp. So it creates the project, but there are .idea and src folder. There isn't source folder. What should I do to be generated "source" folder. I have the dependencies needed. I am using IntelliJ. While using Eclipse I have absolutely the same problem. I fix it with checking "Maven Dependencies" in "Java Build Path/Order and Export". It worked in eclipse, I don't know why. Or can someone tells me how to create project in IntelliJ which has generated pom.xml, web.xml and "source" folder. The question may be stupid, but I really don't know how and obviously I make something wrong.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: The source folder, in a Maven project, is `src/main/java`. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html. Just create it.

Comment: I try this, but when I create such a folder and when I click the `right button -> new` and there is no Java Class. This is screenshot of a sample project from the book I read: http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/29/8568029i.png . I cannot create project like this.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to stick to the maven default project layout convention.
All tooling defaults to this structure (see the link given above).

In Intellij you can easily create a Maven project via the "New Project" dialog.

If you want to keep your current project layout, you can try to right click on your "source/production/java" Folder and click "Mark Directory As" and then "Source root".

This marks it as Java source folder.
You should then be able to create new classes via Context menu.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, very much. After a second try, It accepts this folder as source folder by default, but it is good to know how to manually do this.
Thanks, very much.